# How can I simulate book parts in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I can get a nicely highlighted separation of chapters

[image: chapters; missing parts]

with `book.org`

```
#+title: Species
#+author: CRD
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

# \part{Animals}
* Mandrill
* Mongoose
* Porcupine

# \part{Plants}
* Hydrangea
* Pachysandra
* Spruce
```

and `style.css`

```
body { 
    margin-left: 200px; width: 800px;
}
h2 {
    margin-left: -20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

How do I modify the example above to define a level higher than
chapter? LaTeX has the `\part` command. `Org-mode` appears not to
have anything comparable.

How can I simulate book parts in org-mode?

Comment: Org mode does not have chapters or sections either.  For LaTeX export, the mapping between different levels of headlines and different levels of a book/report/article is done through `org-latex-classes`.  For HTML export, you have to do your own mapping by hand (e.g. how do you know that the above setup produces chapters? Answer: you don't because it does not produce "chapters" - it's just a one-to-one mapping between headlines in Org mode and headlines in HTML) and perhaps use some CSS to format it as you wish.

Comment: See [LaTeX header and sectioning structure](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html) in the Org mode manual.